# Why won't methode notFound work in both ways?

Tags: c#, database, api

I'm currently working on a group project, which involves the use of an web API. I'm using C# ASP.NET Core 2.2 API project with additional classes and all the other blah blah blah.

The data is connected to an Azure database and it works. The problem is requesting an get with an id attached to it. For some reason the methode doesn't work or is being called unless I use it in the if and else statement.

I've added some code below:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<List<User>> GetUser(int id)
{
    var user = UserContext.User.AsQueryable().
        Where(i => i.id == id).ToList();
    if(user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        return user;
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if I did this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<List<User>> GetUser(int id)
{
    var user = UserContext.User.AsQueryable().
        Where(i => i.id == id).ToList();
    if(user != null)
    {
        return user;
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

This:

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<List<User>> GetUser(int id)
{
    var user = UserContext.User.AsQueryable().
        Where(i => i.id == id).ToList();
    if(user == null)
    {
        return user;
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Only this will make the method work:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<List<User>> GetUser(int id)
{
    var user = UserContext.User.AsQueryable().
        Where(i => i.id == id).ToList();
    if(user != null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Why isn't this working properly? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I think you have the if flipped. If user equals null, you want to return "NotFound". If user is not null, you want to return the user. Becuase it means there is something to return.

Comment: yeah, i've editted the file, cause i was trying thing out and posted it before changing it back, but thanks for the feedback :D

Comment: @Christopher is write. Your API will work only if there's no user with the specified Id. Did you meant to return not found when no such user with the specified Id ? Then swap the return value in the if else statement

Comment: The problem is that neither ways work. Either he founds an id or not, The NotFound method is not getting called.

Comment: @Cleax VS 2019 has so helpful "use explicit type" refactoring command - if you don't get why some code with `var` does not work let VS automatically change it to explicit type to see what is actually going on... I.e. variable name in `List<User> user` would look very ridiculous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query with no results does not return null; it returns an empty list.

So change your null check to a length count, or use SingleOrDefault.

```
var users = UserContext
    .User
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where
    (
        i => i.id == id
    )
    .ToList();
if (users.Count != 1)
{
    return NotFound();
}
else
{
    return users.Single();
}
```

Or

```
var user = UserContext
    .User
    .AsQueryable()
    .SingleOrDefault
    (
        i => i.id == id
    );
if (user == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
else
{
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Funny thing they actually explicitly decided to have list and knew it's not null (otherwise `.ToList()` will NRE)…